# Error when using FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String, ?> env)

Tags: java, io, path, uri, nio

I'm using the following code:

```
private static FileSystem createZipFileSystem(String zipFileName, boolean create) throws IOException {
    final Path path = Paths.get(zipFileName);
    final URI uri = URI.create("file:" + path.toUri().getPath());
    final Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<String,String>();

    if(create) {
        env.put("create", "true");
    }

    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
}
```

When I call it (dest is a folder in my project):

```
createZipFileSystem("dest", true);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkUri(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:86)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:326)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:276)
at com.jerney.ziptest.utils.ZipNIO.createZipFileSystem(ZipNIO.java:19)
at com.jerney.ziptest.utils.ZipNIO.getFileSystem(ZipNIO.java:23)
at com.jerney.ziptest.App.main(App.java:15)
```

I've tried using "jar:file:", "file:/", and "file://" for the URI.create() method, and I've tried adding a "/" to the end of "dest" but I get the same results every time. I've seen another solution on SO recommending to use a different FileSystems factory method, but I'd like to use this constructor in particular and know why this isn't working for me.

Comment: can you print `path.toUri().getPath()` ?

Comment: `file:/valid/path/to/dest/`

Comment: so `"file:" + "file:///valid/path/to/dest/"` did you find it logic?

Comment: Why do you create an `URI` like this: `final URI uri = URI.create("file:" + path.toUri().getPath());` when `final URI uri = path.toUri();` should be enough?

Comment: @ThomasKläger, you're right that it's a bit roundabout, but I checked your suggestion and the results are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `FileSystemProvider` has it's own URI prefix. If you use the `file:` prefix you are effectively requesting the default `FileSystemProvider` (depending on your machine either an instance of `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider` or `sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider`).

If you want to use the `ZipFileSystemProvider` you need a `jar:` prefix:

```
private static FileSystem createZipFileSystem(String zipFileName, boolean create) throws IOException {
    final Path path = Paths.get(zipFileName);
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
    final Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<String,String>();

    if(create) {
        env.put("create", "true");
    }

    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use a zip, just a regular directory at this point.

Comment: @Josh if you look at the JDK source (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java#UnixFileSystemProvider#85 and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystemProvider.java#77) you can see that this is not supported by the `UnixFileSystemProvider`

Comment: Been a while, but I'm accepting anyway, seems others have found this useful, even though it didn't solve my problem!